# Overwrite 'Personal info' field in the admin/Users?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

During my first Django app i've managed to hit this 'road-block' where i'm trying to extend User model from my .forms file where forms.py looks like this:

```
#forms.py

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'phone', 'password1', 'password2']

class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

In my .models file i'm only having a 'Profile' model which is being registered within admin.py:

```
#admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import *
from .forms import UserRegisterForm


admin.site.unregister(User)

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin, UserRegisterForm):
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        (('Personal info'), {'fields': ('phone',)}),
    )

admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)

admin.site.register(Profile)
```

...and i'm getting this back(bare in mind i've tried also passing just my form class which resulted in allot more errors):

```
#error
FieldError at /admin/auth/user/1/change/

Unknown field(s) (phone) specified for User. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class CustomUserAdmin.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/1/change/
Django Version:     3.0.4
```

So the end goal would be to have another field available in my Users/'Personal info'(that's been extended within forms.py) and also would be nice to get that field when creating a new user from within the admin page. Any help/idea would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: 'phone' isn't a django.contrib.auth.models field, check here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py